# In scala how to combine List of Map, of unequal size based on common keys with same value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Input:

```
val list1 = List(
    Map("ID" -> "123", "NAME" -> "P1", "PID" -> "321"),
    Map("ID" -> "456", "NAME" -> "P2",  "PID" -> "333")
)

val list2 = List(
    Map("ID" -> "123", "ADDRESS" -> "A1")
)

val list3 = List(
    Map("PID" -> "321", "PHONE" -> "2222"), 
    Map("PID" -> "789", "PHONE" -> "4444")
)
```

Output:

```
List(
    Map(
        "ID" -> "123", 
        "NAME" -> "P1", 
        "PID" -> "321", 
        "ADDRESS" -> "A1", 
        "PHONE" -> "2222"
    )
)
```

I tried iterating list over flatmate and map, but it had bad time complexity.
Expecting a solution in more functional programming approach, not using loop.
Thanks in advance for helping with providing solution.

```
list1
  .flatMap { l1 =>
    list2
      .flatMap { l2 =>
        list3
          .map { l3 =>

            if ((l1.ID === l2.ID) && (l1.PID === l3.PID)) {

              val data = Map(
                "ID" -> l1.ID,
                "NAME" -> l1.NAME,
                "PID" -> l1.PID,
                "ADDRESS" -> l2.ADDRESS,
                "PHONE" -> l3.PHONE,
              )

              val temp = List(data)
              temp              
            }

          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why `Map`? Why not an [`ADT`](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/j8KWXRLXS96uvi2RK8eyOQ)?

Comment: Yes using an ADT looks clean and more appropriate.
When combining list with for-comprehension it has time-complexity of O(n3).
Can we reduce it ?

Comment: You can use a grouping similar to what @Dogbert has shown. You can check the [sample code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1p3qyhrQTKm0BlFkSZlrwA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(list1 ++ list2 ++ list3).reverse.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

This creates a single list of `Map`s and then reduces them to a single `Map`. The `reverse` is needed so that the earlier values take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

I would first create two `Map`s, one for `ID` -> `ADDRESS` and one for `PID` -> `PHONE` from `list2` and `list3` respectively.

```scala
scala> val addressByID = list2.map(x => x("ID") -> x("ADDRESS")).toMap
val addressByID: Map[String, String] = Map(123 -> A1)

scala> val phoneByPID = list3.map(x => x("PID") -> x("PHONE")).toMap
val phoneByPID: Map[String, String] = Map(321 -> 2222, 789 -> 4444)
```

Then use `for` to assemble the data:

```scala
scala> for {
  x <- list1
  address <- addressByID.get(x("ID"))
  phone <- phoneByPID.get(x("PID"))
} yield x ++ Map("ADDRESS" -> address, "PHONE" -> phone)
val res1: List[Map[String, String]] = List(HashMap(NAME -> P1, PID -> 321, PHONE -> 2222, ADDRESS -> A1, ID -> 123))
```